# Understanding XML in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to understand XML parsing in powershell.

What does `$instance.'property.array'` mean ?

(Consider `$instance` refers to an element.) Why the **single quotes?** Do they signify anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes allow you to refer to an element name which contains dots.  Consider the following xml:

```
<root>
    <property.array>
        <element1 />
    </property.array>
    <property>
        <array>
            <element2 />
        </array>
    </property>
</root>
```

To refer to the first element you would use:

```
$instance.root.'property.array'
```

This would select **element1**, whilst:

```
$instance.root.property.array
```

Would give you **element2**.

Comment: thank you for your answer..
if it is mentioned like $instance.root.property.array.value
does it mean that value is also an elemnt? or is there  any reserved word called value?

Comment: No value is not reserved on an xml object, if you pipe '|' your object through Get-Member you will see what it supports.